# How do I teach edebug to only evaluate some macro arguments?

Tags: elisp-macros, edebug, declare

Currently, edebug doesn't understand the `->>` macro in dash.el.

```
(defun foo ()
  (->> (+ 1 1)
       (+ 2)
       (* 3)
       (format "%s")))
```

`C-u M-x edebug-eval-defun` followed by `M-: (foo)` does not step through the forms inside `->>`. It just shows the value of the whole `(->> ...)` expression.

Looking at [the docs for `declare`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Instrumenting-Macro-Calls.html), I don't think I can teach edebug about all the arguments to `->>`. However, the first argument is a form, so I would like to edebug to step through that. I tried this:

```
(defmacro ->> (x &optional form &rest more)
  "Thread the expr through the forms. ..."
  (declare (debug (form &rest 0)))
   ...)
```

However, this gives me "edebug-match-specs: Too deep - perhaps infinite loop in spec?" when I try to call `edebug-eval-defun` on `foo` afterwards.

Can I annotate a macro so that the first argument is a form, but edebug skips the rest?

Comment: Emacs 25 has a new [`thread-first` macro](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/emacs-lisp/subr-x.el?id=emacs-25.0.95#n63) with an edebug spec, does that help?

Comment: @npostavs that's perfect. Would you like to submit your comment as an answer?

Comment: You better make it a self-answer, I don't really understand how it works, I just recalled a relevant example.